# Странная работа CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: блок **.latest-work**]

[image: блок **.main**]

Вопрос такой: почему расстояние между блоками есть, хотя родитель(он же тег main) элементов **.latest-work** и **.main** не flex. Но когда добавляю к **.latest-work** свойство padding-top: 1rem; то все становится нормально. Может это баг Chrome????

[image: **.latest-work** с padding-ом]

Вот стили

```
.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background: url(../img/anvil.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    &-description {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 5rem;

        &__heading {
            color: $page-color;
            font-size: 2rem;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
            margin-top: 2rem;
        }

        &__text {
            color: $additional-color;
            font-size: 1.3rem;
            line-height: 2rem;
        }
    }

    &-list {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 3rem;
        margin-bottom: 5rem;

        &__item {
            width: 25%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 3rem 2rem;
            margin: 20px;
            background-color: $four-color;
            color: white;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        }

        &__heading {
            font-size: 1.25rem;
            margin-top: 2rem;
        }

        &__text {
            font-size: 1rem;
            margin-top: 2rem;
            line-height: 1.7rem;
        }

        &__icon {
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        &__image {
            max-width: 100%;
            transition: .7s;

            &:hover {
                transform: scale(2);
            }
        }
    }
}

.latest-work {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: $page-color;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
    @include line-gradient(45deg, $four-color, $second-linear-color 2px, 135deg, $four-color, $second-linear-color 2px);


    &__heading {
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin: 5rem 0;
    }

    &__jobs {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    &__job {
        width: 20%;
        margin: 0 1rem 3rem 1rem;

    }

    &__description {
        color: black;
        margin-top: 2rem;

        span {
            color: $page-color;
        }
    }

    &__link {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    &__image {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 16rem;
        height: 16rem;
        transition: .7s;
        opacity: .9;

        &:hover {
            transform: scale(2);
            opacity: 1;
        }

    }
}



Вот верстка
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: url(../img/anvil.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.main-description {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.main-description__heading {
  color: green;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.main-description__text {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.main-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.main-list__item {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 3rem 2rem;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.main-list__heading {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.main-list__text {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.7rem;
}

.main-list__icon {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-list__image {
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.main-list__image:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}

.latest-work {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  color: green;
  /* padding-top: 1rem; */
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

.latest-work__heading {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 5rem 0;
}

.latest-work__jobs {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.latest-work__job {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 1rem 3rem 1rem;
}

.latest-work__description {
  color: black;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.latest-work__description span {
  color: green;
}

.latest-work__link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.latest-work__image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 16rem;
  height: 16rem;
  transition: 0.7s;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.latest-work__image:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <div class='main-description'>
    <h1 class='main-description__heading'>Художественная ковка, выполненные работы</h1>
    <p class='main-description__text'>Услуги которые мы предоставляем</p>
  </div>
  <div class="main-list">
    <div class="main-list__item">
      <div class="main-list__icon"><img class='main-list__image' src="img/fence.jpg" alt="кованый забор">
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-list__heading">Кованый забор</h2>
      <div class="main-list__text">Лицо любого дома, в стиле настоящей "ручной" ковки</div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-list__item">
      <div class="main-list__icon"><img class='main-list__image' src="img/home railing.jpg" alt="перила">
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-list__heading">Перила</h2>
      <div class="main-list__text">Помогут вам подняться после тяжелого дня, но гораздо приятнее когда перила выглядят особенно</div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-list__item">
      <div class="main-list__icon"><img class='main-list__image' src="img/canopy.jpg" alt="навес">
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-list__heading">Навес</h2>
      <div class="main-list__text">Не позволит дождю подмочить ваши порожки, перила и настроение</div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-list__item">
      <div class="main-list__icon"><img class='main-list__image' src="img/chimney.jpg" alt="Ковка">
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-list__heading">Дымоход</h2>
      <div class="main-list__text">Все в доме должно сочетаться, от основания до самой крыши</div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-list__item">
      <div class="main-list__icon"><img class='main-list__image' src="img/fireplace grate.jpg" alt="Ковка">
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-list__heading">Решетка для камина</h2>
      <div class="main-list__text">Больше уюта с великолепной решеткой</div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-list__item">
      <div class="main-list__icon"><img class='main-list__image' src="img/urn.jpg" alt="Ковка">
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-list__heading">Другое</h2>
      <div class="main-list__text">Иногда хочется чего то необычного, но мы и это умеем</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- <div class="main-list">
                    <div class="main-list__item">
                        <div class="main-list__icon"><img src="img/forged fence.jpg" alt="кованый забор"></div>
                        <h2 class="main-list__heading">Кованый забор</h2>
                        <div class="main-list__text">Лицо любого дома, в стиле настоящей "ручной" ковки</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-list__item">
                        <div class="main-list__icon"><img src="img/railing.jpg" alt="перила"></div>
                        <h2 class="main-list__heading">Перила</h2>
                        <div class="main-list__text">Помогут вам подняться после тяжелого дня, но гораздо приятнее
                            когда перила выглядят особенно</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-list__item">
                        <div class="main-list__icon"><img src="img/canopy.jpg" alt="навес"></div>
                        <h2 class="main-list__heading">Навес</h2>
                        <div class="main-list__text">Не позволит дождю подмочить ваши порожки, перила и настроение</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-list__item">
                        <div class="main-list__icon"><img src="img/chimney.jpg" alt="Ковка"></div>
                        <h2 class="main-list__heading">Дымоход</h2>
                        <div class="main-list__text">Все в доме должно сочетаться, от основания до самой крыши</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-list__item">
                        <div class="main-list__icon"><img src="img/fireplace grate.jpg" alt="Ковка"></div>
                        <h2 class="main-list__heading">Решетка для камина</h2>
                        <div class="main-list__text">Больше уюта с великолепной решеткой</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-list__item">
                        <div class="main-list__icon"><img src="img/urn.jpg" alt="Ковка"></div>
                        <h2 class="main-list__heading">Другое</h2>
                        <div class="main-list__text">Иногда хочется чего то необычного, но мы и это умеем</div>
                    </div>

                </div> -->
</section>
<section class="latest-work">
  <h1 class="latest-work__heading">Последние кованые работы</h1>
  <div class='latest-work__jobs'>
    <figure class='latest-work__job'>
      <a href='#' class='link latest-work__link'><img src="img/canopy.jpg" alt="Кованая решетка" class='latest-work__image'>
        <figcaption class='latest-work__description'><span>Уличный навес</span></figcaption>
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure class='latest-work__job'>
      <a href='#' class='link latest-work__link'><img src="img/chimney.jpg" alt="Кованая решетка" class='latest-work__image'>
        <figcaption class='latest-work__description'><span>Кованый дымоход на трубу</span></figcaption>
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure class='latest-work__job'>
      <a href='#' class='link latest-work__link'><img src="img/fence.jpg" alt="Кованая решетка" class='latest-work__image'>
        <figcaption class='latest-work__description'><span>Единичный пролет забора</span></figcaption>
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure class='latest-work__job'>
      <a href='#' class='link latest-work__link'><img src="img/forged fence.jpg" alt="Кованая решетка" class='latest-work__image'>
        <figcaption class='latest-work__description'><span>Элегантный забор под ключ</span></figcaption>
      </a>
    </figure>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: приведи пример своей разметки и стилей воспроизводящих ошибку непосредственно в вопросе

Comment: @Grundy добавил стили

Comment: и пример разметки, для которой с этими стилями воспроизведется проблема

Comment: @Grundy добавил верстку

Comment: я перенес твои стили в сниппет - проблема не воспроизводится. Можешь отредактировать сниппет так, чтобы проблема воспроизвелась?

Comment: @Grundy, добавил

Comment: Форматирование приведи в нормальный вид.

Answer (score 4):

Судя по всему тут дело в [схлопывании отступов](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

`margin` от вложенного элемента вливается в `margin` родительского. Но при указании у родительского элемента `padding` в соответствующем направлении - отступы перестают схлопываться

Ниже упрощенный пример демонстрирующий проблему:

```js
function toggleP() {
  document.querySelector('.latest-work').classList.toggle('pad');
}

function toggleM() {
  document.querySelector('.latest-work').classList.toggle('mrg');
}
```

```css
.main {
  padding: 20px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
}

.latest-work {
  background: aquamarine;
}

.latest-work__heading {
  background: chocolate;
  margin: 30px;
}

.pad {
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.mrg {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="toggleP()" value="toggle padding">
<input type="button" onclick="toggleM()" value="toggle margin">
<section class="main">
  main
</section>
<section class="latest-work">
  <div class="latest-work__heading">Последние кованые работы</div>
</section>
```

Как видно из примера, при добавлении у родителя `margin` - отступ не меняется. При добавлении `paddgin` - меняется.

Comment: сталкивался со схожей проблемой,  когда section идет за section. И если в следующем элементе нет padding'a - сразу же рисует невидимые марджины между элементами. Но добавление паддинга хотя бы  в один пиксель - помогает.

Comment: @NeedHate, это не невидимые марджины, это марджины вложенных элементов

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо большое за ответ!!